# MVC - JSON.stringify not working when publishing app to IIS7

Tags: json, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5

During my debugging phase everything with JSON.stringify(editedRows) was working fine on my local development server. I deployed my app to an IIS7 server and JSON.stringify(editedRows) stopped working when I browsed to the site. When I logged onto the server to launch the app from IIS, JSON.stringify(editedRows) worked. I looked over some posts, but nothing seem to solve this issue. Has anyone run into this issue? Thank you.

```
 $('#SaveJobs').on('click', function () {

    var editedRows = getEditedRows(); // get rows from a grid
    alert('Before JSON'); // I see this alert
    var json = JSON.stringify(editedRows); 
    alert('After JSON'); // I do not see this alert and my browser keeps waiting
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well I added a reference to the `json2.js` script, which I did not have in my library of scripts and it worked. I am still confused on why it was working on my dev machine and when I logged onto the server without this library. I am using IE 10 and my other JS libraries are below. If somebody with more knowledge on this subject know please post it below. Thank you!

```
  "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
   "~/Scripts/json2.js",
   "~/Scripts/jquery.event.drag.js"
```

Comment: I found that I needed to open a new session too in addition to refreshing the page.